# Save Perl hash permanently even script exit

Tags: perl, file, hash

I wanted to create a hash table that can save key and it's value permanently even when the scripts exit. Is that possible ?

for example:

For the first time I run this script , it take in $key and $value variable and store it into the hash table.

```
$key = 'perl';
$value = '123';
$hash{$key} = $value;
```

for the second time when I run the same script, but I changed the value

```
$key = 'ruby';
$value = '456';
$hash{$key} = $value;
```

and if i print out the hash table I will get perl with value 123 and ruby with value 456.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience using it, but you can use [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
store \%hash, 'file';
```

Alternatively, you can use a database or key-value store (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Couchbase, Riak, etc).

Comment: Thanks...that's good but is there anyway i can get around without using any module ?

Comment: Yes. Copy and paste the source code, and compile the XS file. Or roll your own. Or write a daemon. But why do you want to make this orders of magnitude more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: `Storable` is a core module in modern Perl; you don't have to worry about whether it is installed or not.  Another option is `Data::Dumper` (another core module) which produces legible output that can be re-read to reconstitute the original data.

Comment: I guess i will stick with writing it to a file and do some processing from there onwards :). Thanks!

Comment: Alright i will try to use Storable to see how it works ! Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

While I agree Storable works, you can also use Data::Dumper which can provide a human readable /modifiable output.  You can also read the data back into a Perl data structure.

Output

```
print $FH Data::Dumper->new([$hash_data], ['output123'])->Purity(1)->Dump;
```

Input

```
my $data_structure = do { local $/; <$FH> };
eval $data_structure;
```

One $data_structure is eval'd you will have a hashref @ $output123.  $output is named by the parameter set when you initially did the dump.

Comment: I just saw @Jonathan Leffler suggesting the same.

Answer (score 1):

Write it to a file.

(extra characters to get to the 30char min post len)

Comment: hi what if i do not want to write it to a file instead i just want to save it in a variable something like environment variable.

Comment: Programs, by definition, do not persist.  And you normally cannot change the environment of the calling process.  Jack Maney's recommendation of Storable is good, and will abstract much of this away for you, but you have to intentionally store data somewhere if you want to store it somewhere.